# Why does Dr. Stelline work for Wallace?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

Why does Dr. Anna Stelline work for Niander Wallace?

As far as I can tell,

> Deckard and Rachael gave birth to her and sent her to an orphanage,

but what exactly happened afterward? How did she get her own laboratory and end up working for Wallace after being in that ratty orphanage?

Answer (score 7):

## She doesn't, she's a subcontractor

Dr. Stelline emphasises that she doesn't actually work for Wallace, rather that she's a subcontractor of his.

In her discussion with K:

> **K:** You work for Wallace?
>   **Ana:** Subcontractor
> <sub>-Paraphrased from memory</sub>

She runs her own business developing memory implants, which she *supplies* to Wallace.

You may have noticed that when K asked her about it, she was quick to reply with "subcontractor", as though she herself wasn't comfortable with the idea of working for Wallace herself.

As for how she got that facility, it's unclear, however, it's safe to assume that either:

- She worked as a successful memory manufacturer already

  - So she paid for it herself, slowly building up her wealth like any other person
- Her 'parents' were well off

  - And left her with enough wealth to either get started, or fund the special room of hers
- The Resistance ('Replicants Underground') helped her

---

It's all quite fishy to say the least, and to me, it seems like there's more to her story than just what she tells <s>us</s> K. See [How could Ana Stelline survive childhood?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171447/how-could-ana-stelline-survive-childhood) for example.